# Stop stuck Apex Jobs

Tags: scheduled-apex

I have the following problem. There is Apex Jobs that stuck in 'Queued' status -

[image]

and because of this Schedulable class can't be modified.

I want to remove this job, but... System.abortJob fail with error. Can anyone advice smth? I tried following ids:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of [Cannot save Apex class or deploy code, with error: 'Schedulable class has jobs pending or in progress'](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004423&language=en_US).

In particular:

> you can enable "Allow deployments of components when corresponding Apex jobs are pending or in progress" under Deployment Settings.

See [Deployment Connections and Options](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=changesets_about_connection.htm&siteLang=en_US). This includes several other options. In the worst case there are details for escalating to support.